# Adding line breaks to XML text

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to use System.Xml.Linq to implement some logging for a small hobby application. I have a few strings that I would like to display in multi-line indented format for clarity, but I cannot get any xml viewer to recognize newline characters. I've found several related posts ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504890/how-to-add-a-newline-line-break-in-xml-file)) ([b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding)) ([c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485037/xdocument-text-node-new-line)) ([d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020088/how-can-i-recognize-a-new-line-in-an-xml-attribute-in-firefox)) ([e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml/10923392)) but the method described doesn't seem to work. My logging code looks as follows:

```
public static void InitializeNewReport(NPCInfo npcInfo)
    {
        if (Logger.Instance.LogCurrentNPC)
        {
            npcInfo.Report = new XElement("Report");
            npcInfo.CurrentElement = npcInfo.Report;
            npcInfo.ReportElementHierarchy = new Dictionary<XElement, XElement>();
         
            LogReport("Patching NPC " + npcInfo.LogReportingString, false, npcInfo);
            Logger.Instance.CurrentNPC = npcInfo;
        }
    }

    public static void OpenReportSubsection(string header, NPCInfo npcInfo)
    {
        if (Logger.Instance.LogCurrentNPC)
        {
            var newElement = new XElement(header);
            npcInfo.ReportElementHierarchy.Add(newElement, npcInfo.CurrentElement);
            npcInfo.CurrentElement.Add(newElement);
            npcInfo.CurrentElement = newElement;
        }
    }

    public static void LogReport(string message, bool triggerSave, NPCInfo npcInfo) // detailed operation log; not reflected on screen
    {
        if (Logger.Instance.LogCurrentNPC)
        {
            AddStringToReport(npcInfo.CurrentElement, message);

            if (triggerSave)
            {
                Logger.Instance.SaveCurrentNPCLog = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddStringToReport(XElement element, string value)
    {
        var split = value.Trim().Split(Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (var item in split)
        {
            element.Add(item);
            element.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    public static void CloseReportSubsection(NPCInfo npcInfo)
    {
        if (Logger.Instance.LogCurrentNPC)
        {
            npcInfo.CurrentElement = npcInfo.ReportElementHierarchy[npcInfo.CurrentElement];
        }
    }

    public static void SaveReport(NPCInfo npcInfo)
    {
        if (Logger.Instance.LogCurrentNPC)
        {
            if (Logger.Instance.SaveCurrentNPCLog)
            {
                string outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(PatcherSettings.Paths.LogFolderPath, Logger.Instance.PatcherExecutionStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Logger.Instance.CurrentNPC.LogReportingString + ".xml");

                XDocument output = new XDocument();
                output.Add(npcInfo.Report);

                var file = new System.IO.FileInfo(outputFile);
                file.Directory.Create(); // If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.
                output.Save(outputFile);
            }

            Logger.Instance.LogCurrentNPC = false;
            Logger.Instance.SaveCurrentNPCLog = false;
        }
    }
```

When viewed in a browser (Firefox), the [resulting log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEmgE.jpg) does not preserve the newlines. When viewed in Notepad++, the log [does preserve the newlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm11P.jpg) but [doesn't preserve the collapsible sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ya94.jpg) because it [places the section tags adjacent to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqQO4.jpg). I can [manually add a line break between the sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX5r9.jpg) to make NP++ [recognize them as collapsible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC7m2.jpg) but that's not a scalable solution. I've also tried replacing

```
foreach (var item in split)
        {
            element.Add(item);
            element.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

with

```
foreach (var item in split)
        {
            element.Add(item);
            element.Add("&#10;&#13;");
        }
```

as suggested in the linked posts but this just [gets incorporated as a literal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZV3Y.jpg) in the output xml. Indeed, when I try to use an online xml viewer, [none of the methods in the linked posts seem to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjB9j.jpg) with a small demo input.

Based on the referenced posts it seems like what I want should be possible, but I'm at a loss as to how to implement it. Could someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Although said you cite [(a), a canonical answer regarding line breaks in XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35504890/290085), the rest of your question proceeds as if you did not understand its key point that how line breaks are rendered is *application-specific*.  There is no universal solution because the XML standard doesn't demand that applications render line breaks in XML files in any particular manner.

Comment: Add differing OS conventions to differing application semantics and you can hopefully see why you shouldn't be expecting rendering/viewing consistency at this level.  HTML uses `<br>` for line breaks to conquer these challenges, for example.