# Problem with \t \n with NSString

Tags: iphone, formatting, nsstring

I have a plist where I place my strings, with type string.
When I access the strings in the plist, it doesnt interpret `\n` and `\t`.

So when I display these strings it will display `\tTitle` 
and not Title with tab indention.

But if I use

```
#define str1 @"\tTitle"
```

and just place it in header files, it works.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004386/how-to-save-newlines-in-xml-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with the way you are accessing the string. Take a look here: [Property list programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD)