# How to preserve whitespace in attributes when using XMLStreamWriter?

Tags: java, xml

When using the javax.xml.XMLStreamWriter, is there any way to preserve the whitespace within attributes? I understand that the XMLStreamReader will perform [Attribute-Value Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize), converting `\r\n\t` in the XML into a space, so it's up to the writer to emit entity references (e.g. `&#13;&#10;`) to preserve the whitespace. Is there any way to tell the writer to use entity references for whitespace? Can I add entity references to attributes myself?

The following JUnit3 test passes. When I encode `"Hello,\r\n\tworld"`, I want to get the same thing back out. But instead, the decoded value is `"Hello  world"` (two spaces).

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
public class XmlStreamTest extends TestCase {
    public void testAttribute() throws XMLStreamException {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);
        xmlStreamWriter.writeStartDocument();
        xmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement("root");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeAttribute("a", "Hello,\r\n\tWorld! ");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeEndElement();
        xmlStreamWriter.writeEndDocument();
        xmlStreamWriter.close();
        assertEquals("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root a=\"Hello,\r\n\tWorld! \"></root>", stringWriter.toString());

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(stringWriter.toString());
        XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(stringReader);
        assertEquals(XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT, xmlStreamReader.getEventType());
        assertEquals(XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT, xmlStreamReader.next());
        // This is not what I want! I want the value to be the same as I originally gave!
        assertEquals("Hello,  World! ", xmlStreamReader.getAttributeValue(null, "a"));
        assertEquals(XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT, xmlStreamReader.next());
        assertEquals(XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT, xmlStreamReader.next());
    }
}
```