# Encode attribute newlines in XMLEventWriter

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am doing some surgical XML transformations using `XMLEventReader` and `XMLEventWriter`.  For the most part, I just write the events as they are read:

```
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class StaxExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException {
        String inputXml =
                "<foo>" +
                "   <bar baz=\"a&#10;b&#10;c&#10;\"/>" +
                "   <changeme/>" +
                "</foo>";

        StringWriter result = new StringWriter();

        XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(inputXml));
        XMLEventWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLEventWriter(result);

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
            //in real code, look for "changeme" and insert some stuff
            writer.add(event);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

My problem is, this produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><foo>   <bar baz="a
b
c
"></bar>   <changeme></changeme></foo>
```

While syntactically valid XML, it's necessary (due to a downstream consumer) that I preserve the newlines.  The above XML will instead be normalized to `a b c` by that consumer (and indeed, by StAX itself--if I take this output and feed it back into the same program, the second time it will output `baz="a b c "`).

While I've given up on `XMLEventWriter` preserving non-semantic formatting, is there a way to prevent it from essentially changing my attribute values?

Comment: Similar question for XMLStreamReader/Writer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331364/how-to-preserve-whitespace-in-attributes-when-using-xmlstreamwriter.  No answer there either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suggest you implement your own Writer:

```
public class EscappingNLWriter extends FilterWriter
{
    public EscappingNLWriter(Writer out) {super(out);}

    public void write(c)
    {
        if (c=='\n')
        {
            out.write("&#10;");
        }
        else
        {
            out.write(c);
        }
    }

    public void write(char[] buff, int offset, int len) throws IOException
    {
        // ...Same char filtering...
    }

    public void write(String str, int offset, int len) throws IOException
    {
        // ...Same char filtering...
    }
}
```

And then use it to encapsulate the StringWriter:

```
Writer result = new EscappingNLWriter(new StringWriter());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the attention and answer!  I'm not sure how practical this will be because it will also replace newlines within tags (e.g. between attributes in tags), not just in character data.  Is it really safe/equivalent to replace *all* newlines encountered in a document with numeric references?

Comment: Yes, all. Numeric entities are lexically equivalent to their represented symbols, anywhere along the XML file.

Comment: What about in CDATA sections?

Comment: In CDATA... Well, numeric entities would have no effect: They would be interpreted as characters, not as entities. I must right myself: _Almost_ anywhere along the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an *absolute accuracy* about *where* to escape newlines in the XML and *where* not to (i.e.: you need to escape newlines only within attributes and not elsewhere), I have another suggestion tough a little more complicated:

Look at your code:

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
        //in real code, look for "changeme" and insert some stuff
        writer.add(event);
    }
```

There is one point where you can **interpose** between the attribute and the writer: Just after initializing `event` and before passing it to `writer.add`, you can **encapsulate** the event in your own implementation of `XMLEvent` to ensure that if it is an instance of `javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute`, you will overwrite `Attribute.getValue()` to return the value properly escapped.

**But there is an extra complication**: The XMLEvents returned by a XMLEventReader usually do not include Attribute events: Attributes are included within its corresponding StartElement events. So you need one more level of encapsulation: The StartElement objects and then the contained Attribute objects.