# $.parseXML is dropping \r\n

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

When parsing an xmlstring, the \r\n is lost. How to solve that?

```
//Example
var string = "<x y=\"line1\r\nline2\"></x>",
    xml = $.parseXML(string),
    y = xml.documentElement.getAttribute("y");
//Now y is missing the \r\n.
```

Comment: Use escape `\\` for each `\r` `\n`

Comment: @Java_User thanks. That works. I'm getting the value from an textarea, so expected the escaping is done by them. A setAttribute on xml works without escaping. Lessons learned and thanks again.

Comment: Also see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004386/how-to-save-newlines-in-xml-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line break in an attribute value is meaningless.

```
<foo bar="line1
line2" />
```

is really equivalent to:

```
<foo bar="line1 line2" />
```

Encode your attribute value like this instead:

```
<foo bar="line1&#xA;line2" />
```